# Deleting a bitmap resource in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, resources

I am trying to delete a resource bitmap through code and am having trouble doing it. Went through several hours of headbanging with google. Here is the code:

```
int result; 
HANDLE h;
h = BeginUpdateResource(L"C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\stub.exe", FALSE);
result = UpdateResource(h, RT_BITMAP, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP2), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL), NULL, 0); 
EndUpdateResource(h, FALSE);
```

When I debug, variable "result" ends up being NULL which means that the update didn't go through. Is there something incredibly basic that I'm missing?

Comment: Been there, banged my head... it's not fun :(

Comment: Just to be paranoid, have you checked the return value of `BeginUpdateResource`? What does `GetLastError` say after `UpdateResource`?

Comment: Dumb question, but "stub.exe" isn't running or in use is it?  Your resource update code is running in another app - stub.exe isn't trying to update itself, is it?

Comment: The return value of BeginUpdateResource gives an address - so it's successful. How do you do a GetLastError? I tried this in the immediate window to no avail. stub.exe is NOT running. No, it's not trying to update itself. Do I have to do a "LoadResource" or something before I do a BeginUpdateResource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what went wrong. First off, I used the "GetLastError()" command to help widdle down the possibilities. It gave me an error 0x57 which means ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

When I experimented more, it seems that in the language paramters, I listed "MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL)" instead of "MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US)". Apparently, resources care about the language you are using even if it's something like a bitmap which doesn't use language.

Once I put in LANG_ENGLISH paramters, it worked. You can find out what language you are using by inspecting the text of the .rc that the resource is using to build.,